# working with join query's result

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables Resources and Categories. I have made a join query and got the result. But I dont know how to work around it.  Below is outputted result array.

```
array (size=4)
0 => 
   array (size=5)
  'resourceID' => string '24' (length=2)
  'resourceName' => string 'Tafe Resources' (length=14)
  'categoryID' => string '3' (length=1)
  'categoryName' => string 'Accounting' (length=10)
  'subcategoryID' => string '0' (length=1)
1 => 
array (size=5)
  'resourceID' => string '24' (length=2)
  'resourceName' => string 'Tafe Resources' (length=14)
  'categoryID' => string '4' (length=1)
  'categoryName' => string 'Adult Tertiary' (length=14)
  'subcategoryID' => string '0' (length=1)
2 => 
array (size=5)
  'resourceID' => string '26' (length=2)
  'resourceName' => string 'College Resources' (length=17)
  'categoryID' => string '7' (length=1)
  'categoryName' => string 'Automotive' (length=10)
  'subcategoryID' => string '0' (length=1)
3 => 
array (size=5)
  'resourceID' => string '26' (length=2)
  'resourceName' => string 'College Resources' (length=17)
  'categoryID' => string '8' (length=1)
  'categoryName' => string 'Busniess & Management' (length=21)
  'subcategoryID' => string '0' (length=1)
```

this was my query

```
$this->db->select()->from('resources');
$this->db->join('categories','resources.resourceID = categories.resourceID');
```

if it was from single table i will use for-each loop and get data.
I want the duplicated columns to be merged.
I want to display a table where resourceID and resourceName is unique.

Comment: You probably want to change the query to get the results you want; show the query.

Comment: As far as PHP is concerned, a result from a query **IS** a single table. The field names may differ a bit, but the act of retrieving data from a joined query result is absolutely the same as retrieving data from the result of a single table query.

Comment: I need to display as table where the resources are unique and categories merged to each resources

Answer (score 0):

How do you want the table to be unique? You could use [`GROUP BY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html) but you would lose the category information for any duplicates of resourceID and resourceName.

Edit: You can use a JOIN with a [`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) for a subquery but that would limit you to the max length set for the concat operation.

I think the best solution would just to loop through the data and set the data to ensure the rows for resourceID and resourceName are unique.

Comment: I need to display as table where the resources are unique and categories merged to each resources –

Comment: @user3002327 Can you please provide an example of what output you're expecting, I can't exactly grasp the phrasing of what you're looking for.

Comment: From the example, resourceID 24 and its categories 3 and 4 should come in one row. can you get it